# Compact operators are orthogonally equivalent to a diagonal matrix?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

On Brezis's [*Functional Analysis*](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387709130), the last question of Problem 44 (near the end of the book) reads (modified to include context)

> Assume that the Hilbert space $H$ is separable and $T\in\mathcal K(H)$ (but $T$ doesn't necessarily satisfy the following condition: there exists an isometry $J\colon\ker T\to\ker T^*$), the set of compact operators on $H$. Prove that there exist two orthogonal bases $(e_n)$ and $(f_n)$ of $H$ such that
>   $$Tu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n(u,e_n)f_n$$
>   where $(\alpha_n)$ is a sequence of nonnegative real numbers and $\alpha_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Since one should assume the operator to be partial isometric instead of orthogonal/unitary, as [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#Bounded_operators_on_Hilbert_space) pointed out. Even if the operator is compact, I think it's still necessary since we can compose the one-sided shift with a compact operator corresponding to a diagonal matrix.

So I think this question is in fact false, but I doubt that I got stuck somewhere, since Brezis stressed in the parenthesis that the condition about existence of isometry isn't necessary. I want your help to clarify my misunderstandings. Thanks!

Comment: sort the $\alpha_n$ by absolute value. for extracting $\alpha_1$ consider $\max_{\|v\|=1} \|Tv\|$, you'll get $\alpha_1 = \|Tv\|$, $e_1 = v$, $f_1 = \frac{T v}{\alpha_1}$. then consider $T_2 = Tu - \alpha_1 (u,e_1)f_1$, and repeat iteratively. (that's the basic SVD algorithm). finally suppose that the alogorithm doesn't converge, that the obtained $\alpha_n$  don't tend $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and show that the operator then cannot be compact.

Comment: @user1952009 The real issue is "at" the singular value $0$. In fact, even in general, for polar decomposition, we need to assume partial isometric instead of unitary because of $0$. If $\ker T$ is isometric to $\ker T^*$, then everything works for unitary operators in polar decomposition.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. what I see only  is supposing that $H$ is a separable complex Hilbert space, and probably that we have some sort of axiom of choice, that's all.

Comment: @user1952009 Then, for example, why does $(e_n)_n$ constitutes a Hilbert base? I mean, it (Hilbertly) spans $H$.

Comment: @user1952009 I need to point out that it's wrong without restriction: consider the case $T$ has infinite singular values but $0$ is also a singular value (namely, $\ker T\neq0$).

Comment: $T$ is of course supposed to be bounded (and compact if it helps). if we can show there exists an unitary operator $U$ such that $ TU$ is self-adjoint, then the spectral theorem ensures that $TU = V D V^*$.

Comment: The $0$ operator is compact, and you don't get that representation because the $\alpha_n$ must all be $0$.